# C# - App Crash When Using Ping event

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, network-programming, ping

i'm working with ping Librarry in net 3.5 to check the presence of IP.

take a look at the code below:

```
    public void PingIP(string IP)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(ping_PingCompleted); //here the event handler of ping
        ping.SendAsync(IP,"a"); 
    }

void ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
       //On Ping Success
    }
}
```

Then i execute the code through Thread or backgroundworker.

```
private void CheckSomeIP()
{
        for (int a = 1; a <= 255; a++)
        {
            PingIP("192.168.1." + a);
        }
}
```

> ```
> System.Threading.Thread checkip = new System.Threading.Thread(CheckSomeIP);
> checkip.Start();
> ```

Well, here is the problem:

**If i start the thread then i would to close the application (Close with Controlbox at corner), i would get "App Crash"
although i have closed/abort the thread.**

I think the problem is event handler? as they still working when i'm closing the Application so that i will get **"App Crash"**

What would be the best way to solve this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think, on a successfull Ping, you are trying to update the interface from within the Thread, which will cause an CrossThreadingOperation exception.

Search the Web for ThreadSave / delegates:

```
public void PingIP(string IP)
{
    var ping = new Ping();
    ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(ping_PingCompleted); //here the event handler of ping
    ping.SendAsync(IP,"a"); 
}

delegate void updateTextBoxFromThread(String Text);

void updateTextBox(String Text){
   if (this.textbox1.InvokeRequired){
       //textbox created by other thread.
       updateTextBoxFromThread d = new updateTextBoxFromThread(updateTextBox);
       this.invoke(d, new object[] {Text});
   }else{
      //running on same thread. - invoking the delegate will lead to this part.
      this.textbox1.text = Text;
   }
}

void ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
       updateTextBox(Text);
    }
}
```

Also on "quitting" the application, you may want to cancel al running threads. Therefore you need to keep the reference on every thread you start somewhere in your application. in the formClosing-Event of your Main-Form, you can force all (running) threads to stop.

Comment: No, i don't write the code that cause an "CrossThreadingOperation exception" at all. i have closed all the thread but it all doesn't work. therefore i thought the event handler was the problem.

Comment: Have you know, if we ping the IP that not active, it will take a lot time to get the reply that they "Timed Out" rather than active IP, so if we Close the Application when we were getting "bad request" it will cause app crash